# Navigation menu flickers when moving from page to page, only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, navigation, flicker

I have an issue on a website I'm creating. The navigation menu flickers when you move from page to page but only in Chrome and IE.

What's even more strange is that it doesn't happen when I open it in an icognito window on Chrome or when I load it locally.

Here's a live example - http://andrewbruce.me

I'll put the code below -

Navigation HTML -

```
<body>

<div class="menuButton" onclick="decide(this);">
  <div id = "bar1"></div>
  <div id = "bar2"></div>
  <div id = "bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id ="nav">
     <ul>
        <a href = "home.html"><li>HOME<span style = "float: right; padding-right: 2%;">></span></li><a/>
        <a href = "portfolio.html"><li>PORTFOLIO<span style = "float: right; padding-right: 2%;">></span></li><a/>
        <a href = "cv.html"><li>CV<span style = "float: right; padding-right: 2%;>></span></li><a/>
        <a href = "contact.html"><li>CONTACT<span style = "float: right; padding-right: 2%;">></span></li><a/>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Navigation CSS -

```
#nav {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 22%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #1b1d1f;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2;
    margin-top: 20%;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a Chrome extension installed which was slowing down the performance of my browser so it was loading the navigation bar slowly.

Hence why it was working in incognito because none of the extensions were loading!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your site in both Chrome and Safari and I can not seem to recreate the flickering. The flickering could be due to load speed and the navigation bar is just loading in. Based on the fact that it only occurs when on a public server. When your doing a local test the speed tends to be instant, since it is pulling directly from files on your computer.